# TFS Board Consolidation with Multiple Projects

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2012 in which we are having multiple projects.
As far as I know, the board visibility is limited to one project on its current sprint.
Is there any possibility/addin to consolidate the TFS board using multiple projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not support to show work items from multiple Team Projects on a single Kanban board in TFS for now.

Just like you mentioned, Kanban boards in TFS are currently associated with an Sprint path (scurm)/Iteration Path(Agile). An iteration path only exists within the context of a Team Project. As such, Kanban boards by their current implementation live only within a Team Project.

As a workaround, you could move multiple projects into the same Team Project and  use Teams instead. Then you could use different sprint/iteration paths or area paths to differentiate your work items. Otherwise you need to use some third party tool or sites help you tracking such as [Kanban Tool](http://kanbantool.com/), simply by creating swimlanes on one Kanban board (one swimlane for each project).

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/visibility-across-teams?view=vsts

The Delivery Plans extension does what you're looking for.  Letting you combine multiple sprints from different teams into a single view.